# Python Converting output into sentence

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, nltk

I just started learning python. I was trying to clean a sentence by breaking into words and joining back to a sentence. the document big.txt has some words like youth, caretaker etc. The problem is in the final procedure : looper , This produces an output by each line.

Correct is an another procedure defined before this code that corrects each word

here is the code :

```
zebra = 'Yout caretak taking care of something'

count = len(re.findall(r'\w+', zebra))

def looper(a,count):
words = nltk.word_tokenize(zebra)
for i in range(len(words)):
    X = correct(words[i])
    print (X)

final = looper(zebra)
```

The output it produces:

```
youth
caretaker
walking
car
in
something
```

How should I take all the individual outputs and make a sentence:

Expected Result:

```
youth caretaker walking car in something
```

Please let me know if you need additional details.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use list comprehension:

```
print " ".join([ correct(words[i]) for i in range(len(words)) ])
```

it should be like this:

```
zebra = 'Yout caretak taking care of something'

count = len(re.findall(r'\w+', zebra))
words = nltk.word_tokenize(zebra)
def looper(a,count):
    print " ".join([ correct(words[i]) for i in range(len(words)) ])
```

the words should be out of the function, you don't need to get words every time while looping.

you can use this too:

```
print " ".join([ correct(i) for i in words ])
```

here is the correct way to do it:

```
zebra = 'Yout caretak taking care of something'
words = nltk.word_tokenize(zebra)
print " ".join([ correct(i) for i in words ])
```

you dont need a function here , as words is list of words, you can iterate and join.

in your code:

```
zebra = 'Yout caretak taking care of something'
words = nltk.word_tokenize(zebra)
for x in words:
    print correct(x),
```

demo:

```
>>> zebra = 'Yout caretak taking care of something'
>>> words = nltk.word_tokenize(zebra)
>>> words
['Yout', 'caretak', 'taking', 'care', 'of', 'something']
```

As you can see `nltk.word_tokenize` give you list of words, so you can iterate through them easily,

Comment: provide a reason for downvoting

Comment: desired output is `youth caretaker walking car in something` not only tokenized words

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import nltk
>>> zebra = 'Yout caretak taking care of something'
>>> for word in nltk.word_tokenize(zebra):
...     print word
... 
Yout
caretak
taking
care
of
something
```

Then `$ sudo pip install pyenchant` (see https://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/api/enchant.html) and:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> import enchant
>>> zebra = 'Yout caretak taking care of something'
>>> dictionary = enchant.Dict('en_US')
>>> for word in nltk.word_tokenize(zebra):
...     dictionary.suggest(word)
... 
['Out', 'Yost', 'Rout', 'Tout', 'Lout', 'Gout', 'Pout', 'Bout', 'Y out', 'Your', 'You', 'Youth', 'Yous', 'You t']
['caretaker', 'caret', 'Clareta', 'cabaret', 'curettage', 'critical']
['raking', 'takings', 'tasking', 'staking', 'tanking', 'talking', 'tacking', 'taring', 'toking', 'laking', 'caking', 'taming', 'making', 'taping', 'baking']
['CARE', 'acre', 'acer', 'race', 'Care', 'car', 'are', 'cares', 'scare', 'carer', 'caret', 'carte', 'cared', 'cadre', 'carve']
['if', 'pf', 'o', 'f', 'oaf', 'oft', 'off', 'sf', 'on', 'or', 'cf', 'om', 'op', 'oh', 'hf']
['somethings', 'some thing', 'some-thing', 'something', 'locksmithing', 'smoothness']
```

Then try:

```
>>> for word in nltk.word_tokenize(zebra):
...     print [i for i in dictionary.suggest(word) if word in i]
... 
['Youth']
['caretaker']
['takings', 'staking']
['cares', 'scare', 'carer', 'caret', 'cared']
['oft', 'off']
['somethings', 'something']
```

So:

```
>>> " ".join([[word if dictionary.check(word) else i for i in dictionary.suggest(word) if word in i][0] for word in nltk.word_tokenize(zebra)])
'Youth caretaker taking care of something'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
zebra = 'Yout caretak taking care of something'

count = len(re.findall(r'\w+', zebra))

def looper(a,count):
words = nltk.word_tokenize(zebra)
for i in range(len(words)):
    X = correct(words[i])
    print X,    
final = looper(zebra)
```

just add , after X --->`print X,`

Comment: Thanks Alex, but this method did not work, it doesnot give me any output